# Radix-4 multiplication problem with unknown simulation output

Tags: verilog, simulation, shift-register, multiplier

I'm writing code in Verilog that takes `A` and `B` as 8-bit inputs and multiplies them using the radix-4 method.

When I execute the code, the `shft` output appears as "xx0", and `mutipler` can't take the value of the input A.

Can any one help me with that?

This is the sub-code:

```
module pha1 (A, B, M ,clk, shft);
  input wire [7:0] A, B;
  input clk;
  output reg [7:0] M;
    
  reg [7:0] mutipler;
  
  output reg[2:0] shft;

  reg init;

  initial 
    init=1'b0;
  initial 
    mutipler=A;
  
  always @(posedge clk)
  begin
    shft = {mutipler[1], mutipler[0], init};
  end 
endmodule
```

This is the testbench :

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module pah1tst;
reg [7:0] A;
reg [7:0] B;
reg clk;
wire [9:0] M;
wire [2:0] shft;

pha1 uut (
    .A(A), 
    .B(B), 
    .M(M), 
    .clk(clk), 
   .shft
);

initial clk = 0;
always #2 clk = ~clk;

initial begin
    A = 2;
    B = 5;
    #5;
    #34;
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

You only assign `mutipler` once at time 0 in the `initial` block.  Since a `reg` always initializes to X (the unknown value in Verilog), the initial value of `mutipler` will be `3'bxxx`.  You do assign it the value of `A` at time 0, but `A` is also likely to have all X, too.

Do you really need `mutipler`, or can you just use `A` as follows?

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    shft <= {A[1:0], init};
end
```

Comment: i know that was  the problem ,but i can't find another way to do that

Comment: I want to shift the input A many times ,so mutipler is really needed to save the new value after shifting

Answer (score 0):

"initial" only happens once at time zero. Try:
assign mutipler = A;

Better yet, why not just use A directly.

Use non-block assignment for clocked logic (less likely to get unintended behavior):
shft <= {mutipler[1],mutipler[0],init};

In general, implement reset for clocked logic so you can force known states at start of simulation.

(By the way I don't know radix-4 multiplier.)